# Configuring linux to be visible in microsoft DNS domain

Tags: linux, likewise-open, dhclient, mdns

I've been trying to have one of our linux box available in the windows domain. The linux box is a ubuntu server without gui or X installed. All manipulations are done from ssh.

Linux box:

- hostname: cactus
- fqdn: cactus.example.com
- ip: 10.0.1.121

Microsoft AD + DNS:

- hostname: example.com
- ip: 10.0.1.115

I followed some tutorials but It still not working. I installed likewise and added my linux box to active directory. I can login using

```
ssh 'domain\user'@10.0.1.121
```

But I can't login or ping : `cactus.example.com`. On my workstation, the nameserver is correctly set to 10.0.1.115 and pinging example.com return the correct ip. But my domain is still invisible.

I heard I only had to join to the domain to make it visible but apparently it's not working.

Any idea how to get that linux box hostnamed resolved by other machine in the network?

**Edit**

I created an A record under

**Forward Lookup Zone**

+--> example.com

....+--> host: ip: static

It shows up as static but ping is still not working.

Comment: Have you checked whether an A record has been created on your DNS server for cactus? If not, then Ryan's suggestion sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually add a static A record in DNS for cactus.  The Linux server with Likewise installed doesn't have the same "automatically register with DNS" function that Windows clients do.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea how to do it on windows.

Comment: RDP to Windows DNS server. Open Server Manager. Expand DNS. Locate the DNS zone that represents your domain. Right-click in the pane where all the other A records are. Choose "New -> A record"

Comment: I apparently added it. In the DNS Manager under Forward lookup zone. I can see there other subdomains but I still can't ping my host.

Comment: ipconfig/flushdns on the client from where you're attempting to ping. And make sure you are using that same Active Directory / DNS server on your client for name resolution.

Comment: Seems to work now, I'm from OSX and running `dscacheutil -flushcache` wasn't enough. I restarted the wifi and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function to register automagically with DNS.

```
lw-register-dns
```

Just build it into a cron, like this one:

```
1 */1 * * * /opt/likewise/bin/lw-update-dns --ipaddress X.X.X.X &> /dev/null
```